# CNN train with weird result: VAL LOSS increases while VAL ACCURACY / PRECISION / RECALL also increase

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am fine tuning a 5 classes with model Resnet50 w/ 10 millions trainable parameters. Data has around 140,000 samples and 20% are used for validation. Batchsize 256 I may add and lr is warming linearly from 1e-5 up to 3e-4 for first 10 epochs then cosine annealing twice from there for another 20 epochs (10 - 30), we than flat the lr at 5e-6 from epochs 30th to 40th. Each classes have a lot in common but easily are differentiated.

The picture attached said it all: after epoch 10, **everything are increasing**, both val loss, val accuracy, val precision and val recall (not to mention also F1, top-1 etc... also increase steadily). In practice, the prediction give a lot of false positive than expected with very high probability of 99%.

What really happened here may I ask ?

...

```
base_model =  ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalMaxPooling2D(name='feature_extract')(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(len(classIDs), activation="softmax", name='all_classes_hatto')(x)
classifier = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=[x])
```

...

Thanks for your helps. Steve[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Four (4) things have to be done:

1) Data is a concern, hence clean data a bit more

2) Put more noice into the model

3) Batchnorm after activation at almost last layer

4) Switch to DenseNet201 which learns much deeper

```
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalMaxPooling2D(name='feature_extract')(x)
# Add Gaussian noices
x = GaussianNoise(0.5)(x)
# Add batchnorm AFTER activation
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='linear')(x)
# Add batchnorm AFTER activation w/o DropOut
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dense(len(classIDs), activation="softmax", name='all_classes_hatto')(x)

classifier = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=[x])
```

This works and I finally got an oustanding model now (the blue line).

[image]

Steve